# Find after populate mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some trouble querying a document by values matching inside the document after population by mongoose.

My schemas are something like this:

```
var EmailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: String
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Email'}]
});
```

I would like to have all users which have a email with the type = "Gmail" for example.

The following query returns empty results:

```
Users.find({'email.type':'Gmail').populate('email').exec( function(err, users)
    {
      res.json(users);
    });
```

I have had to resort to filtering the results in JS like this:

```
users = users.filter(function(user)
        {
          for (var index = 0; index < user.email.length; index++) {
            var email = user.email[index];
            if(email.type === "Gmail")
            {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        });
```

Is there any way to query something like this straight from mongoose?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**@Jason Cust** explained it pretty well already - in this situation often the best solution is to alter the schema to prevent querying `Users` by properties of documents stored in separate collection.

Here's the best solution I can think of that will not force you to do that, though (because you said in the comment that you can't).

```
Users.find().populate({
  path: 'email',
  match: {
    type: 'Gmail'
  }
}).exec(function(err, users) {
  users = users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.email; // return only users with email matching 'type: "Gmail"' query
  });
});
```

What we're doing here is populating only `email`s matching additional query (`match` option in `.populate()` call) - otherwise `email` field in `Users` documents will be set to `null`.

All that's left is `.filter` on returned `users` array, like in your original question - only with much simpler, very generic check. As you can see - either the `email` is there or it isn't.

Comment: I would just note a bit of concern if `users` is a large collection with this approach.

Comment: @JasonCust: indeed! That's probably why still the best option would be to alter the schema properly (which can be not-so-fun if, for example, you already have working application and some data in the DB). I also thought about alternative solution: 1. Fetch `_id`s of properly filtered e-mails ( `Emails.find()` ), 2: Load only users with e-mails matching those ( `Users.find()` with `$in` operator). I can post example of this solution too if you're interested. On one hand, no loading of all users documents. On the other hand, it seems even more hack-ish/workaround-ish.

Comment: But this will not work with pagination. I am also stuck in this situation where i have to paginate the data as well. So what happens now is on page 1 I am getting empty array but one page 2 i am getting filtered data. Can anyone help in this??

Comment: I wasted too many hours too access fields of populated path. Although I can log populated field "User" correctly, If I try to access field in it, "user.firstName" , directly, it throws error. Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'string'. Because its a reference type on both TS interface and model.

//Logs correctly
`{
  user:{
       firstName:"Hasan",
       lastName:"Mehmet"
}
}`

I'm just tired and gonna filter the result array as you do.

Answer (score 10):

Mongoose's [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) function doesn't execute directly in Mongo. Instead after the initial `find` query returns a set a documents, `populate` will create an array of individual `find` queries on the referenced collection to execute and then merge the results back into the original documents. So essentially your `find` query is attempting to use a property of the referenced document (which hasn't been fetched yet and therefore is `undefined`) to filter the original result set.

In this use case it seems more appropriate to store emails as a subdocument array rather than a separate collection to achieve what you want to do. Also, as a general document store design pattern this is one of the use cases that makes sense to store an array as a subdocument: limited size and very few modifications.

Updating your schema to:

```
var EmailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: String
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: [EmailSchema]
});
```

Then the following query should work:

```
Users.find({'email.type':'Gmail').exec(function(err, users) {
  res.json(users);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation about how populate works, that's very insightful. The example I gave was a simplification, my actual use case does require referenced documents so I really have to find a solution to this without changing the model.

Comment: @Rubelet Currently there is no concept of a `join` in MongoDB so MongooseJS won't be able to do more than what it is currently designed to do in this case. I think a concern with attempting to query the collection this way is that if it's a large collection the population would be a costly operation to do. If this is how the schema must be I would look into using a stream and filtering to avoid causing a bottleneck during the population.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any other solution other than using Aggregate. It will be more troublesome, but we will use Lookup.

```
{
       $lookup:
         {
           from: <collection to join>,
           localField: <field from the input documents>,
           foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
           as: <output array field>
         }
}
```