# Find document by filtering sub-document Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently using Express and I'd like to create a route like this :

```
router.get('/actionsFiltered/:company/:user/:location',function(req,res,next){
  var query=Action.find({
    company:req.company._id,
    inCharge:req.user._id,
    'event.location':req.location._id,
  })
  .populate({
    path:'event',
    populate:[{path:'eventLocation'},{path:'anomaly'}],
  })...
```

My Action knows an Event by having an attribute 'event' referring to a Mongo ObjectID. My Event object have an attribute 'location', referring to a Mongo ObjectID too. I want to get the **actions only if the parameter location match the location id owns by the event, itself owns by the action**.

Here's an action :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591ecadd97d6f32bf0c6f3e7"),
    "company" : ObjectId("58eceb1d2a59fa1c5c4dfc9d"),
    "event" : ObjectId("591174b9ce02550140214bd3"),
}
```

Here's an event :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591174b9ce02550140214bd3"),
    "location" : ObjectId("586e9559b38f2a101caa77fc"),
}
```

And finally a location :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586e9559b38f2a101caa77fc"),
    "name" : "Wsh",
}
```

**'event.location':req.location._id** doesn't work but I don't know how to do the request. I could add the location field directly in the Action object but I don't want to if possible.

Comment: Are you using [app.param](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param) ? If not, you should be using [`req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find after populate mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357745/find-after-populate-mongoose)