# Find after populate in array of object

Tags: mongoose

I would like to 'find' the following item, based on its 'guess.body':

```
{
        
        "guess": [
           
            {
                "body": "findme",
            }
        ],
        "_id": "608ee73b18a16e39e809203f"
}
```

This item is located in a collection called "ask", with the following model:

```
const askSchema = new Schema ({
guess: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'guess'}],

})
```

In order to do this, I've tried 2 queries:

- The first one:

  ```
   const askByGuess = await ask.find().populate("guess").find({"guess.body":"findme"})
   res.status(200).json(askByGuess)
  ```

which return an empty arrary

- the second one (based on this answer: [Find after populate mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357745/find-after-populate-mongoose))

  ```
   const askByGuess = await ask.find().populate({path:"guess", match{body:"findme"}}).exec(function(err, ask) {ask = ask.filter(function(ask) {return ask.guess})})
   res.status(200).json(askByGuess)
  ```

which returns "1".

Could someone indicate to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to agree with the solution presented in [Find after populate mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357745/find-after-populate-mongoose), however, if for your specific use case you could get by a simple **aggregation** pipeline:

`$unwind`: to populate the **guess** field.
`$lookup`: performs a left outer join.
`$match`: to finally match your search term.

```js
db.ask.aggregate({
  $unwind: "$guess"
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "guess",
    localField: "guess",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "guess"
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    "guess.body": "test"
  }
})
```

Here's a working snippet: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bJgC4rSvb_9

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `populate` since the `guess` property is not reference to another Collection. Try this:

```
const askByGuess = await ask.find({
  guess: {
    $elemMatch: {
      body: "findme"
    }
  }
})
res.status(200).json(askByGuess)
```

Here is the working snippet: https://mongoplayground.net/p/isBMZ3Fa8QB

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Unfortuantely, populate IS necessary, as guess does refer to another collection. Here is the model FYI. 
const askSchema = new Schema ({
alert: {type: Boolean, default: false, required: false},
guess: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'guess'}]
})
Sorry for not specifying it in my first message.