# Mongoose query on multiple populated fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I have three collections i.e `Events`, `News` and `FuneralNews`.
I have another `Notifications` collection that is just a combination of all three and contains the reference Id of either/one of the three collections.

I want to fetch only those `Notifcations` whose eventId OR newsId OR funeralNewsId field `isActive` is true

**EventsSchema**:

```
var EventsSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  isActive: Boolean
});
```

**FuneralNewsSchema**:

```
var FuneralNewsSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  isActive: Boolean
});
```

**NewsSchema:**

```
var NewsSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  isActive: Boolean
});
```

**NotificationSchema:**

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  eventId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Events'},
  newsId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'News'},
  funeralNewsId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'FuneralNews'},
  organisationId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization'}
});
```

This was my query before I need a check on `isActive` property of referenced collection:

```
  let totalItems;
  const query = { organisationId: organisationId };

  Notification.find(query)
    .countDocuments()
    .then((count) => {
      totalItems = count;
      return Notification.find(query, null, { lean: true })
        .skip(page * limit)
        .limit(limit)
        .sort({ creationDate: -1 })
        .populate("eventId")
        .populate("newsId")
        .populate("funeralNewsId")
        .exec();
    })
    .then((notifications, err) => {
      if (err) throw new Error(err);
      res.status(200).json({ notifications, totalItems });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      next(err);
    });
```

Now I don't know how to check on `isActive` field of three populated collections prior population.

I have seen other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31357745/9399066) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11303294/9399066) but being a newbie can't edit it according to my use-case. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$lookup` for each objectId refrence
then `group` by _id of null to get data and add myCount as total number put original data to array
and use `unwind` to destruct array and use `addField`

```
model
  .aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "Events", // events collection name
        localField: "eventId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "events",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "FuneralNews", //FuneralNews collection name
        localField: "funeralNewsId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "funeralnews",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "News", // news collection name
        localField: "newsId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "news",
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          { "news.isActive": true },
          { "events.isActive": true },
          { "funeralnews.isActive": true },
        ],
      },
    },

    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        myCount: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
        root: {
          $push: "$$ROOT",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$root",
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        "root.total": "$myCount",
      },
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$root",
      },
    },

    {
      $sort: {
        creationDate: -1,
      },
    },
  ])
  .skip(page * limit)
  .limit(limit);
```

Comment: Thanks Naimi. What about countDocuments? where to adjust it.

Comment: you could use another stage in aggregate pipeline as `{$count:"countfieldname"}`

Comment: Thanks but the query isn't populating the referenced doc. I want population too

Comment: after `count` you need population data ?

Comment: Yes, I want events, news, funeral details too after isActive check

Comment: so you have count of all docs and event news funeral ?

Comment: count of notifications having active event/news/funeral + event/news/funeral details (from population)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236803/discussion-between-mohammad-naimi-and-artsnr).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tweaking it a bit (using $slice while grouping as pagination wasn't working fine) solved my issue so marking it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: PS: I am a bit confused about the performance optimisation. Is it a bad approach to reference and populate three collections like this (my schema)

Comment: for performance issue check this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742635/poor-lookup-aggregation-performance